# How to convert UTM to Lat/Long?

Tags: javascript, map-projections, proj4js, utm

Is there a way to convert [UTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) to Lat/Long in Javascript?  I have seen another thread on this but it was in Java and Python which won't help me much.  Please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Can't you just convert the Java/python to javascript?

Answer (score 20):

You could use Proj4js, as follows.

Download Proj4JS from GitHub, using [this](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js) link.

The following code will convert from UTM to longitude latitude

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="proj4.js"></script>

  <script>
    var utm = "+proj=utm +zone=32";
    var wgs84 = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
    console.log(proj4(utm,wgs84,[539884, 4942158]));
  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

In this code, the UTM zone is 32, as should be obvious. The Easting is 539884, and the Northing is 4942158. The result is:

```
[9.502832656648073, 44.631671014204365]
```

Which is to say 44.631671014204365N, 9.502832656648073E. Which I have [verified](http://www.rcn.montana.edu/resources/tools/coordinates.aspx?nav=11&c=UTM&md=83&mdt=NAD83/WGS84&z=32&e=539884&n=4942158&h=N) is correct.

If you need other projections, you can find their strings [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/).